# Unsupported media type in httpclient call c#

Tags: c#, rest

I'm a trying to post the following request but I am getting a "Unsupported Media Type" response. I am setting the Content-Type to application/json. Any help would be appreciated. And as per comment below, if i change content as 'new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(root), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")' then i get bad request response

```
string URL = "https://test.com/api/v2/orders/";  //please note it is dummy api endpoint
            var client = new HttpClient();
            var httpRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage
            {
                Method = HttpMethod.Post,
                RequestUri = new Uri(URL),
                Headers = {
                            { HttpRequestHeader.Authorization.ToString(), "Bearer ABcdwenlfbl8HY0aGO9Z2NacFj1234" },  //please note it is dummy bearer token
                            { HttpRequestHeader.Accept.ToString(), "application/json;indent=2" },
                            { HttpRequestHeader.ContentType.ToString(), "application/json" }
            },
                //Content =new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(root), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")
                Content = new StringContent(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(root))
            };
            var response = client.SendAsync(httpRequestMessage).Result;
```

Answer (score 3):

With `HttpClient`, some headers are counted as request headers, and others are counted as content headers. I'm not sure why they made this distinction really, but the bottom line is that you have to add headers in the correct place.

In the case of `Content-Type`, this can be added as part of the `StringContent` constructor, or to the constructed `StringContent` object.

My approach is to use the constructor:

```
Content = new StringContent(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(root), System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
```

Or alternatively set it afterwards:

```
Content = new StringContent(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(root))
Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
```

Note: If your issue still presents after making this change, then it's likely a server-side problem and you'll need to contact the maintainer of the API to ask what you're doing wrong.

Comment: But, when i add this :  Content = new StringContent(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(root), System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");           Then i got response as  'Bad Request'

StatusCode: 400, ReasonPhrase: 'Bad Request', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
{
  Connection: keep-alive
  Vary: Accept
  Vary: Cookie
  Vary: Origin
  Referrer-..................

Comment: And it is not the server side problem because it is working fine from POSTMAN call.

Comment: OK, what you're going to need to do is use a tool like Telerik's Fiddler to capture both the Postman and .NET requests, and then compare your working Postman request to your failing .NET request in their raw forms. I would argue that because you're not receiving "Bad Request", the problem your current question is about has been solved: the server now understands the request, but for some reason it's not happy with it. You should obtain the information I suggested and post a new question about that problem.

Comment: P.S. Note that you can read the response content even for a request for a failure response code. If the server's responses are helpful, it might also give you insight as to what's wrong.

Comment: After implemeting the solution under this heading *Or alternatively set it afterwards:* I stopped banging my head!! Thanks for the answer..

Answer (score -1):

I prefer using some third party wrappers like [FluentClient](https://github.com/Pathoschild/FluentHttpClient)
Note that you should not instance a new object for every request, O only did it for the sake of an example.

```
var client = new FluentClient("https://test.com/api/v2/orders/")
.PostAsync(URI)
.WithBody(root)
.WithBearerAuthentication("ABcdwenlfbl8HY0aGO9Z2NacFj1234");
var response = await client.AsResponse();
```